# How can I selectively copy files from one directory to another directory?

Tags: linux, files, directory, cp

On Linux, how do I selectively copy most – but not all – files from a directory (`dir1`) to another directory (`dir2`)?

I do not want to copy `*.c` and `*.txt` files to `dir2`.

The `cp` man page online cannot help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to eboix's `find` command (which as it stands breaks on whitespace, I'll put a safer way or two at the end), you can use `bash`'s `extglob` feature:

```
# turn extglob on
shopt -s extglob 
# move everything but the files matching the pattern
mv dir1/!(*.c) -t dir2
# If you want to exclude more patterns, add a pipe between them:
mv dir1/!(*.c|*.txt) -t dir2
```

See the `bash` man page for more you can do with extglob.
Note that this is not recursive and so will only move files in `dir1` directly, not subdirectories.  The `find` method is recursive.

---

Safer `find` commands:

```
find dir1 ! -name '*.c' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t dir2
find dir1 ! -name '*.c' -exec mv -t dir2 {} +
```

For more patterns, just add more `! -name` statements:

```
find dir1 ! -name '*.c' ! -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t dir2
find dir1 ! -name '*.c' ! -name '*.txt' -exec mv -t dir2 {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find ./ ! -name '*.c' | xargs -i cp {} dest_dir
```

Comment: This will break on whitespace, you should add `-print0` / `-0` or use `-exec`.

Comment: Or don't use filenames with embedded blanks or special characters (frankly, a good idea!)

Comment: thanks, what if I want to avoid two or more files ? for example, '*.c' or '*.txt' ?

Comment: @user1002288 You add more `! -name ...` statements, I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command from dir1:

cp `ls|egrep -v .txt\|.c` dir2

The part " ls|egrep -v .txt\|.c " will list files without .c and .txt in the name.
cp will copy them to dir2